# Seemingly no gradle import support in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have the full version of IDEA 12.1.6

I am trying to import the gradle project https://github.com/Synesso/jomsocial-automation-test

The import doesn't recognise the project as a gradle project. No dependencies are linked, the java profile is ignored and there is no jetgradle window.

In the IDE settings the only thing that matches a search for "gradle" is the gradle plugin, which is installed by default.

I think I need to configure the IDE to support gradle imports, but can't find what or where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange. Anyway, the Gradle support in IntelliJ 12 is very limited. You are better off with Gradle's `idea` plugin or IntelliJ 13 (EAP), which has *much* better Gradle support.

Comment: Interesting. I tried the idea plugin and it generated old file-based IDEA config. When I opened the project nothing was configured, no dependency libraries, no sources, nada. Does my build.gradle look OK? https://github.com/Synesso/jomsocial-automation-test/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks. I ran the idea target again and it worked this time. Not sure what happened previously.